# py2exe cannot import Module from other directory

Tags: python, py2exe

I am bundling python source code with py2exe. The directory structure is as follows:

```
some_Mod.py
some_dir/another_dir/some_Mod.py
```

Inside the latter some_dir/another_dir/some_Mod.py I am trying to import the other Python Module with

```
from ..some_Mod import *
```

Using the import causes no problems with the python interpreter, but if I run the same constellation in the bundled package, I get an Exception:

```
 ImportError: No module named some_Mod
```

Can somebody explain why?

Remark: Renaming the Modules is actually no problem, but I was just wondering, why py2exe cannot deal with this constellation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have `__init__.py` files in each of those sub-directories then all import statements should work correctly.
 Assuming that's not the problem, here's an excellent guide to importing best practices:

http://blog.habnab.it/blog/2013/07/21/python-packages-and-you/

In summary, never use relative imports - always absolute (see the link above for why).

Second (and I'm not entirely sure why), always keep your py2exe setup.py script in the exact folder where your main script is. I've tried modifying py2exe's 'script' option to allow my script to be somewhere else... but your exact problem happened to me. So, try making sure it is right where the main script is.

Finally, you can always give py2exe a little help. I usually have to add the root directory to the system path so the import statements are valid. Note, I'm not modifying `sys.path` in *any* of my application's code - only the py2exe script I use to build the exe.

At the top of my py2exe setup script:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(PATH_WHERE_PACKAGES_ARE)
# add any packages that need explicit importing here located in root directory:
import package1 # apparently it wasn't found...
import package2 # apparently same thing
```

Generally I don't import packages though, adding the project root where they exist usually is enough.

Comment: Although 'thanks' are discouraged ... I've been fighting with this scenario on and off for a couple of years now, and you've provided a viable solution.  So ... THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that py2exe now how to handle the `from ..some_Mod import *` syntax, check this to ensure that the some_Mod.py module is correctly packaged : `python -m py2exe.mf -d some_dir/another_dir/some_Mod.py` as explained in the [py2exe FAQ](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/FAQ)

Comment: According to http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/News py2exe should import relative imports.

Comment: well, is the module some_Mod.py present in the generated library.zip ?

Comment: Both modules are present. I opened the library.zip which is created by py2exe and it contained the same directory structure.